# systemd pathexists not triggered when booting

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

I tried to configure my trackpoint sensitivity on my ArchLinux using the systemd path unit as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrackPoint#systemd.path_unit

My files look like this:

```
/etc/systemd/system/trackpoint_parameter.path
-----
[Unit]
Description=Watch for, and modify, Trackpoint attributes

[Path]
PathExists=/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

And

```
/etc/systemd/system/trackpoint_parameter.service
-----
[Unit]
Description=Set TrackPoint attributes

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/trackpoint_configuration.sh
```

So I enabled the path unit and since the file exists my script is executed. Until now everything worked as expected. But when I boot my laptop the path unit is started (according to its status after booting), but it never triggered the service (according to its status) and hence the script is not executed.

If I disable the path unit again (after it booted unsuccessful), suddenly the service unit is triggered.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong/how I can dig deeper?

Comment: Do you actually have a `/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/` directory? On my system, `serio1` and `serio2` are separate directories underneath of `i8042`.

Comment: The directory exists.

Comment: Did `trackpoint_parameter.path` not trigger `trackpoint_parameter.service` after booting or `trackpoint_parameter.service` start already when it got triggered?